# technique of showing a set is a topology

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

> Let $X $ be a set and let $Y\subset X$. Define $\tau_Y $ to be the collection of all subsets U of X such that $Y\subset U $ or $U= \emptyset $ . Prove that $\tau_Y $ is a topology on $X $.

I have successfully been able to show that this is in fact a topology, my question has to do with the right technique to use.

Initially before i got a hint given to me, to show the properties of finite intersection and arbitrary union, i started with letting $x\in U_1\cap U_2$ for example and then i wanted to proceed from there. Continuing in this manner i didnt't get anywhere far. But once i instead just considered $U_1\cap U_2$ and then dissected each set into their respective cases i was able to succeed in showing the necessary conditions. So after doing some pondering about it i realized that i was somewhat robotically just jumping into the technique of showing that a point from one set is contained in another set without thinking about the problem and what it asked.

**Question**
So in attempting to reconcile techniques to solve containment problems, I want to ask if the following thought of mine would be a good way of thinking about things.

> - If the respective set has conditions involving the individual points then it is here where i would show a point from one set is contained in another set.
> - If there is nothing specific about points attempt to just show the necessary conditions are satisfied in regards to the sets alone.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking here. The straightforward way to check that a collection of subsets forms a topology is to apply the definition, while how you do so depends on how the subsets are defined. In this case all you need to do is verify that: 1. $Y \subseteq X$, 2. the union of infinitely many sets containing $Y$ contains $Y$, 3. the intersection of any two sets containing $Y$ contains $Y$. Depending on the level of rigour required in this exercise, you could either say that 2 and 3 are obvious, or you could prove them by looking at any given point in $Y$.

Comment: In the huge amount of fluff that i wrote, i think you summarized it easily in saying that how i show that the definition of a topology is satisfied depends on how the subsets are defined. So if a subset is defined in terms of characteristics of the points i would show a point in one set is also in another set. But if there is nothing discussing the individual points i would use the sets being discussed, exactly in the way you did above